# Авто билды/тесты/залики magento проектов при помощи docker

Tags: docker, magento, непрерывная-интеграция, devops

Интересует **непрерывное развёртываение** magento проектов с **docker** использованием контейнеров.
Моя логика следующая (после `push/merge` в ветку).

1) Описать **Dockerfile** с набором ПО как на **Live** сервере

2) Внутри контейнера клонировать файлы с репозитория

3) Стягивать с **Live** базу данных и другие **файлы**, которые находятся в `.gitignore`

4) Производить установку средствами `composer`, `npm` и тд

5) Запускать автотесты

6) Если все прошло, спуливать изменения на **Live** сервере.

При таком подходе процедура под номеров `3` очень тормозит процесс. Файлы качаются долго, да и трафик не резиновый. К тому же, если какой-то из пунктов **зафейлится**, нужно будет делать все заново.

Возможно есть какие-то готовые решения, которые помогают в этом? Буду рад их услышать.

**PS:** В сфере `DevOps` не так давно, поэтому не судите строго.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) Внутри контейнера клонировать файлы с репозитория

Стягивать репозитории с `--depth=1`.

> 3) Стягивать с Live базу данных и другие файлы, которые находятся в .gitignore

Ускорения можно добиться, если не качать каждый раз. Как сделать?
Загружать только при изменениях (свежий бекап базы, файлы) и загружать на CI c Live сервера. Инструменты, да различные, rsync, сделать cron задачу.

> 4) Производить установку средствами composer, npm и тд

Очень много безполезного трафика. Нужен кеширующий сервер для артефактов (composer, npm, etc). Например [squid](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-squid).

Сделав все эти шаги, уменьшите трафик и ускорите весь процесс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я знаю что есть CD сервисы, по типу OctopusDeploy, которые помогаю в деплое. Что вы используете для автоматизации?

Comment: Вначале bash простые скрипты типа build and push в docker registry. Посложнее на python по всем сервисам с проверкой существования образа. Ansible для deploy в docker swarm (copy secrets, stack).

Comment: То есть если я правильно понимаю, то на сервере нужно поставить squid как прозрачный прокси, а http(s), ftp в контейнерах настроить на на 0.1:3128?

Comment: Да, example для npm ... `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`
`npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Поставил squid, столкнулся с проблемой. Он отлично кэширует http, но вот https нет, точнее со включёнными опциями skip ssl validate для разных сервисов (npm, wget, curl), он также кэшируют хорошо, но если , например использовать composer, но не умеет отключить проверку, только полностью выключить поддержку https, в то время как некоторые пакеты тянутся только по https. Пытался играться с настройками squid, но желаемого результата не получил. Получалось проксировать ssl, но в таком случае он не кэширует трафик. У вас было подобная проблема?